# fwrite() hangs when running process through mod_php as upstream, but fine solo

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I seem to be having issues with running wkhtmltopdf through a proc_open() on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10.

What seems to happen (on several servers) when running solely with Apache is that the process is opened successfully, the data is written to and the PDF comes out of the other end of the process.

However, when running the same code through a setup with Nginx as a proxy and Apache as the upstream server, the fwrite() to stdin seems to hang/become unresponsive with anything more than approximately 1200 bytes.

The static binary version 0.10.0-rc2 seems to be working fine on its own, and can render any page it can access, so I'm not sure what's causing the issue here.

Edit: It doesn't seem to be Nginx, as I've put that in front of Apache on an AWS box and it still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the result of the Nginx server not having a specific hosts entry for the domain name it was using in the request. The request entered a loop, continually hitting the external address and redirecting to it, rather than resolving locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "tail -f " and run the PHP script. You will hopefully see the error message appearing and that will guide you in the right direction.